# How to reexecute if an error occurs in python?

Tags: python, twint

I'm working with Twint(a Twitter scraper) but somehow there is a problem that I can't fix. I wonder if there is a way that when an error occurs, wait 1 min and re-execute this?
My code is like this:

```
import twint

geos = ["40.74566208501717, -73.99137569478954", "35.68802408270403, 139.76489869554837", "31.22521968438549, 121.51655148017774"]
    
for geo in geos:
    print(str(geo)+','+'10km')
    c = twint.Config()
    c.Limit = 20
    c.Geo = str(geo)+','+'10km'
    twint.run.Search(c)
```

Sometimes,`twint.run.Search(c)` can't function correctly.So, once there is an error, is there a way to only execute this loop again but not re-executing the whole loop?

Would anyone help me? Any idea would be really helpful. Thank you much!

Comment: What happens in the situation where it doesn't function correctly. Does it crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simply pretend the error didn't happen, you could do:

```
try:
    twint.run.Search(c)
except WhateverExceptionType:
    pass
```

(replace `WhateverExceptionType` with the actual type of error you're seeing)

If when there's an error you wanted to have the whole program wait for a minute before continuing the loop, put that in the `except`:

```
import time

...

    try:
        twint.run.Search(c)
    except WhateverExceptionType:
        time.sleep(60)
```

If you want it to re-execute that specific search after waiting (rather than continuing with the next loop iteration), put *that* in the `except`.  Note that if code within an `except` raises, then it will raise out of the `except` and stop your program.

```
    try:
        twint.run.Search(c)
    except WhateverExceptionType:
        time.sleep(60)
        twint.run.Search(c)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For an error like ` twint.token.RefreshTokenException: Could not find the Guest token in HTML`, how could I know what type of error it is?

Comment: `twint.token.RefreshTokenException` -- or if you do `from twint.token import RefreshTokenException` then it's just `RefreshTokenException`.

Comment: It works! thanks!

Comment: Is there an approach to show the error type I get on the terminal?

Comment: Make it `except RefreshTokenException as e` and then `print(e)` inside the `except`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to try the search again after 60 sec and with say maximum 10 retries:

```
import time

for geo in geos:
    print(str(geo)+','+'10km')
    c = twint.Config()
    c.Limit = 20
    c.Geo = str(geo)+','+'10km'

    success=False
    retries = 0
    while not success and retries <= 10:
        try:
            twint.run.Search(c)
            success=True
        except twint.token.RefreshTokenException:
            time.sleep(60)
            retries += 1
        except: # <- catches all other exceptions
            retries = 11  # <- e.g. stop trying if another exception was raised
```

Comment: Looks it has been solved! Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a way to take a look at what error I get in your solution?

Comment: Sure, I just put an example of how you could take different actions depending on the exception that was raised.